# Create a JSON without a key

Tags: java, json, gson

We wanted to create a JSON structure as below in Java

```
{
 [
  { 
   "key": "ABC001",
   "value": true 
  },
  { 
   "key": "ABD12",
   "value": false 
  },
  { 
   "key": "ABC002",
   "value": true 
  },
 ]
}
```

To implement this we created a class and had a list private property inside it.
But that is creating a key `values`

```
class Response{
private List<Property> values;
 // setter getter for this private property
}
```

The output for this is

```
{
values : [
{
"key": "ABC001",
"value": true
},
......
]
```

Is there a way we create the array without the key and inside the `{ }`?

Comment: You are making the json of an instance of the class `Response` instead of the json of a `List<Property>`. Can you please add the code you use to make the json so we can correct it?

Comment: @nonzaprej I tried creating the json from the list<property> itself then it is not inside the { } , It is coming as [ {Key,value} , {Key,vaue} ]. we want it inside  { [ { },{ } ] }

Comment: This doesn't seem like job for List -> Array, try Map -> Object instead

Comment: @AluanHaddad Tried with Map no luck, Same issue it needs a Key

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your objective. Do you jave want a list like `[true, false, true, ...]`? That seems useless. If you just want a `List`, just use a `List`, no need for a wrapper.

Comment: That is also invalid JSON `{[`

Comment: I mean, if you want, you can add the `{` and `}` "manually"...

Comment: You don't actually need the Response class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're trying to build is not a valid json.
You can try to validate it [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

With this "json", for example, it would be impossible to read the array, because it has no key.

```
{
"foo_key" : "bar",
 [
  { 
   "key": "ABC001",
   "value": true 
  },
  { 
   "key": "ABD12",
   "value": false 
  },
  { 
   "key": "ABC002",
   "value": true 
  },
 ]
}
```

Parsing a json like this one, you could get "bar" because it has a key ("foo_key"), but how could you get the array?

The code you're using is already correct for a valid json.

Answer (score 2):

So, for some reason you want an invalid json, which is an array contained between `{}`s. Here's how you can do it (I'll assume you use google-gson to make and parse jsons, since you didn't include your code):

```
// example of the creation of the list
List<Property> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add(new Property("ABC001", true));
values.add(new Property("ABD12", false));
values.add(new Property("ABC002", true));
//

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(values, new TypeToken<List<Property>>() {}.getType());
json = "{" + json + "}";// gotta do what you gotta do...
```